# Matching specific character, extracting first word LINQ Lists

Tags: c#, linq

Good Evening

I hope someone can help me, I've searched everywhere for a possible solution but I can not find anything, I have a LINQ list in Csharp, now what I have been trying to achieve is this. Upon Matching first occurrence of "a" extract the first word containing the a. Here's my code

```
        List<string> strings = new List<string>()
        {
            "John", "Jane", "Sarah", "Pete", "Anna"
        };

        string strValue = Program.GetSingleStringValue(strings);
        Console.WriteLine("Single String: " + strValue);
```

I am newbie in csharp and Linq so I would really appreciate it so much if someone can help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `First` method with a *predicate*,it will return the *first* element that satisfies the condition or throw an exception if there is no such element.You can use `Contains` to check whether the string contains `a`

```
string strValue = strings.First(s => s.Contains('a'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
var result = strings.Where(x=> x.Contains('a')).FirstOrDefault();
```

or directly use `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
var result = strings.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Contains('a'));
```

it will give you the element which contains alphabet **a** in it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

I think you need the word which starts with `a`:-

```
string wordWitha = strings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("a",
                                            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

If you want any word which contains `a` then:-

```
string wordWitha = strings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains('a'));
```